# How to re-use the same Page Layout, but apply different styles?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, page-layout

I am currently working with SharePoint 2010 to make an intranet at work.  I have very limited experience with it.

I need to create a page layout.  In my mind, a page layout is a way of displaying the different containers in the page, not styling the page. Maybe I'm wrong here and if so, you can tell me.

The layout I am currently creating will be one that will be re-used in many sub-sections of the intranet.  The problem is that they want each of these sections to have its own color.

I have no idea how to do that without creating the same Page Layout with different styling.  What I would like to achieve is to re-use the same Page Layout, but apply a different CSS depending on the sub-site.

At first I thought that Themes would be the way to go, but it seems that it is too limited.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the page layout should not have styling. That is what share point also do.

The styling / branding (SharePoint Term) depends on Master Page CSS Link and Themes.

For your case, it is better to use different Site Themes for different sites. Go to site setting->Look and Feel -> Site Theme.

But if all sites have different master page, then you can put different CSS links in Master Page, which is lengthy and developer work,

Thanks
Let me know if you still have questions.